# Android - NestedFragments participate in populating the options menu

Tags: android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

i am implementing the new nested fragment feature and had stumble into a problem.
my view is basically this:
a main activity(**A**) that includes a fragment(**B**), this fragment(**B**) includes a pager adapter that has 3 pages each of them is a fragment(**C**) also.
previously to the new getchildfragmentmanger this was not doable, but it works perfectly.
but one issue did arise, i want fragments C to be able to participate in populating the option menu.
i tired putting setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the onActivityCreated method on each of my **C** fragments and overriding also onCreateOptionsMenu but nothing happens...
if i try to populate the menu from fragment **B** (which is the container of the pager adapter) i can change the menu items...

any thoughts ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Yes they can.

With android 4.2 or support library revisiion 11 nested fragments participate in populating options menu, as allways you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` during `onCreate()`.

But if you are using ActionBarSherlock they won't, you have to manually call from parent fragment `onCreateOptionsMenu()` nested fragment method `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

**Update**: [issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/828)

Comment: Are you sure about that? I am using ActionBarSherlock but as far as I know ABS just uses normal ActionBar when the device is above ICS. I am using nested fragments and support revision 11 but the menu is not created.

Comment: @tasomaniac Yes, i am sure. And you always can look in the source of ABS and android, as i did. Problem is not in actionbar, problem in the way ABS handles calls to onCreateOptionsPanel() from FragmentActivity to fragments and not to nested fragments.

Comment: You are saying that if I not use ActionBarSherlock and compile it with Android 4.0 and use support library I can use onCreateOptionsMenu in nested fragments?

Comment: @tasomaniac Yes, and not only from android version 4.0, support library runs on android 1.6 and up. And you also can use onCreateOptionsMenu() with ActionBarSherlock as i wrote in my answer.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was calling it manually. Hope Jake Wharthon fix this in the next update.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this saved me quite some time.

Comment: @kreker this issue solved or not? or any alternative solution available? I'm getting this same issue SherlockActivity(with navigation bar) ----> SherlockFragmentTabstrip (withpagerAdapter) -->SherlockFragment(child fragment that I failed to call Option-menu)

Comment: @kreker Thnx! can you explain how to call child fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu() manually  from parent fragment? like this? getChildFragmentManager().onCreateOptionsMenu() in parent fragment? it is not working!  looks like I have migrate from ABS to ABC?

Comment: @LOG_TAG well, find them somehow in code...
I didn't use ABC.

Answer (score 11):

From my read of the source code, it appears that the implementations of `FragmentManager` and `Activity` only work with the root `FragmentManager` for adding to the options menu/action bar, not and child `FragmentManager` instances.

Fragment B presumably will need to manage the options menu/action bar on behalf of the contents of the `ViewPager`, changing what is in the options menu/action bar based upon the pages being shown and hidden in the pager.

Comment: hi CommonsWare, thanks for your fast replay, that's what i ended up doing, but i was hoping for a more encapsulated solution.

Comment: Yes..!! i got stuck on this issue too.. and i did what mark murphy has told.. Thanks mark

Comment: may I know how is your workaround working? I tried everything and it's still messed up..