# Nested Fragment Not able to inflate OptionMenu using ActionBar Sherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to change the menu buttons in  my action bar each time when fragment is changed.
It work well for normal fragments .

However when i am trying to change the menu in action bar when changing child fragments , it is not working .
onCreateOptionMenu is not called in case of child fragments  .

Is there any way to inflate the menuitems when child fragments are added .

I am using sherlock action bar.

[Android - NestedFragments participate in populating the options menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787287/android-nestedfragments-participate-in-populating-the-options-menu)